# What happens when I upgrade a boosted building?

Tags: clash-of-clans

One can boost resource collectors (elixir pumps/drills and gold mines), hero recovery, barracks and spell factories, to make them work faster for a while. I know a barracks boost gets "paused" when the servers are down forward maintenance and one can "resume" them boost when one's ready to profit from it again.

But what happens when I upgrade a boosted resource collector (and render it inactive forward a while). Does the boost get paused? Or is it just a waist of the gems used for boosting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't upgrade a boosted building.

When you attempt to upgrade a boosted building, the game will prompt you asking whether you would like to have the boost cancelled.
After the boost is removed, you'll be able to start the upgrade.

Remember that cancelled boosts **cannot be reinstated.**